# Sobolev space and norms

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Hello I'd like to know the solution to this question in my Numerics of PDE's class. Here goes:

Given $V := \lbrace v \in H^1(0,1): v(0) = 0 \rbrace \subset H^1(0,1)$
Show that the $H^1$-seminorm $|\cdot|_1$ is equivalent to the $H^1$-norm $||\cdot||_1$ on V.

We have naturally that $|v|_1\leq||v||_1$, but the other inequality, I can't seem to find a good way.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  Use the boundary condition, $v(0)=0$.

Comment: Yes.. But I come from physics, and am now majoring in mathematics, and I'd like to know how you come up with an answer to this sort of question. Have you seen a similar problem before, or are you plainly gifted?

Comment: $|v(x)| = |v(0) + \int_0^x|v'(x) dx| \leq (Cauchy-Schwartz) |v(0)| + \int_0^1|v'(x)|dx =\int_0^1|v'(x)|dx = |v|_1$

Comment: $||v||_1^2 = |v|_1^2+||v||_0^2 = |v|_1^2+\int_0^1v(x)^2dx \leq |v|_1^2+|v|_1^2\int_0^1dx = 2|v|_1^2$

Comment: Start with the definitions.  This (inter alia) is a reason to ask you for more context.  Some will post "questions" about norms and semi-norms without quite knowing the difference, etc.  Assuming that is not the case here, we ask ourselves how the "gap" between them can be made up (and in general there really is a gap).  The extra information here is that $V$ consists only of functions $v\in H^1(0,1)$ s.t. $v(0)=0$, so that must be the critical condition that allows an argument to go through.

Comment: This is the solution, but 2 questions: 1. We have that $|v(x)| \leq |v|_1 $ that does not imply that $|v(x)|^2 \leq |v|_1^2$ ? But we use this in the second part? And even if this somehow works, we end up with $|v_1| \leq ||v||_1 \leq \sqrt{2}|v_1|$ How is this equivalence between the norms?

Comment: I apologize for this wild goose hunt, I really just wanted to see if someone could just mix up the answer by themselves, because honestly when I meet problems like this, I can't, and in general I don't know anyone who can.

Comment: Last question first:  It is a matter of definition, that two norms are *equivalent* iff there exist constants $c,C \gt 0$ such that $c||f||_a \le ||f||_b \le C||f||_a$.  Here we abusing (very slightly) the term since we are asked to show "equivalence" of the $H^1$ norm with the corresponding semi-norm.

Comment: This "wild goose hunt" is sometimes called "the journey of mathematics".  Good questions are often more valuable than good answers.

Comment: Can you also answer my first one, is it even correct? :) This was a question in my exam, so I'd like to know if the answer is flawed :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me call attention to a technical (but important) detail.  Since functions in Sobolev classes are technically only defined "almost everywhere", how can we impose a condition $v(0)=0$ in a meaningful way?  You have tried to get the required estimate (using the fact that $(0,1)$ has length one), assuming "naively" that we can compute $v(x) = v(0) + \int_0^x v'(t) dt$.  There is something to be said about why this is justified.

It might not be expected on an exam to regurgitate all the "machinery" of Sobolev norm definitions, but a key idea to keep in mind is that $H^1(0,1)$ is defined in such a way that $C^\infty[0,1]$ functions will be *dense* in the topology given by the $H^1$ norm.

So it suffices to prove the estimate $||v||_1 \le C|v|_1$ for some constant $C \gt 0$ (and all $v\in V$, $C$ not depending on $v$) by proving the estimate only for "nice" smooth functions, about which the meaning of $v(0)=0$ has no ambiguity.

Then the gist of your appeal to Cauchy-Schwartz to prove the estimate is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $f\in V$, then

\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{H^1}^2 
&= \int_{0}^1 f(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x + \int_{0}^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \int_{0}^1 f'(x)\left(\int_{x}^1 f(\xi)\, \mathrm{d} \xi \right)\, \mathrm{d} x + \int_0^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
&\le \left(\int_0^1 f'(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/2} \left(\int_0^1 \left( \int_x^1 f(\xi)\, \mathrm{d} \xi \right)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\right)^{1/2} + \int_0^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
& \le \left(\int_0^1 f'(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/2}  \left(\int_0^1 \left( \int_x^1 f(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d} \xi\right)\left(\int_{x}^1 1 \, \mathrm{d} \xi  \right)\, \mathrm{d} x \right)^{1/2} + \int_0^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
& \le \left(\int_0^1 f'(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/2}  \left(\int_0^1 \left( \int_x^1 f(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d} \xi\right)(1-x)\, \mathrm{d} x \right)^{1/2} + \int_0^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
& \le \left(\int_0^1 f'(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/2}  \left(\int_0^1 \int_x^1 f(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d} \xi\, \mathrm{d} x \right)^{1/2} + \int_0^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \left(\int_0^1 f'(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/2}  \left(\int_0^1 \int_0^\xi f(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\, \mathrm{d} \xi \right)^{1/2} + \int_0^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \left(\int_0^1 f'(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/2}  \left(\int_0^1  f(\xi)^2 \int_0^\xi\, \mathrm{d} x\, \mathrm{d} \xi \right)^{1/2} + \int_0^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \left(\int_0^1 f'(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/2}  \left(\int_0^1  f(\xi)^2 \xi \right)^{1/2} + \int_0^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
&\le \left(\int_0^1 f'(\xi)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/2}  \left(\int_0^1  f(\xi)^2 \right)^{1/2} + \int_0^1 f'(x)^2\, \mathrm{d} x\\
&= |f|_{H^1} \|f\|_{L^2}+ |f|_{H^1}^2\\
&= |f|_{H^1} (\|f\|_{L^2} + |f|_{H^1})\\
&\le |f|_{H^1} \sqrt{2} ( \|f\|_{L^2}^2 + |f|_{H^1}^2)^{1/2}\\
&=\sqrt{2}  |f|_{H^1} \|f\|_{H^1} \\
\end{align*}\

So comparing the first line with the last and canceling a factor of $\|f\|_{H^1}$ we get $\|f\|_{H^2} \le \sqrt{2}|f|_{H^1}$  Since I wrote every single step, I leave it to the reader to supply the justifications.

Comment: Impressive, but did you cook this up yourself over half an hour (or less), or did you you know the road before you set out? I mean, how could you possibly see that was going to work seven inequalities down the line?

Comment: One my professors told me something I think about a lot.  He said, "An applied mathematician really only has two tools, Cauchy Schwarz and integration by parts." So just started banging on it with that.  To be honest though, I think the better approach is to write $u(x) = \int_0^x u'(\xi)\, \mathrm{d} \xi$ instead.

Comment: Hehe, impressive, and optimistic! I would have left the trail after one bend, I guess it comes down to faith

Comment: Ha, faith or Masochism.  These kind of estimates are pretty common, so the trick of canceling the factor at the end is also common.

Comment: We have a university priest, maybe I should go

Comment: As an exercise you should try to prove a similar result for the subset of $H^1$ with zero mean.  I am confident you would only need to use Cauchy Schwarz, integration by parts, and Fubini.